# ¿Hay otra forma de imprimir un producto cartesiano en un diccionario que tiene arreglos como valores siguiendo un orden específico en Python?

Tags: python-3.x, itertools

Digamos que tengo el siguiente diccionario:

```
the_dictionary_list = {'Color': ['Amarillo.png', 'Blanco.png', 'Rojirosado.png', 'Turquesa.png', 'Verde_oscuro.png', 'Zapote.png'], 
                       'Cuerpo': ['Cuerpo_cangrejo.png'], 
                       'Fondo': ['Oceano.png'], 
                       'Ojos': ['Antenas.png', 'Pico.png', 'Verticales.png'], 
                       'Pinzas': ['None', 'Pinzitas.png', 'Pinzotas.png', 'Pinzota_pinzita.png'], 
                       'Puas': ['None', 'Arena.png', 'Marron.png', 'Purpura.png', 'Verde.png']}
```

Una forma de imprimir cada combinación posible es usando `itertools`, así:

```
import itertools as it

AllKeysNames = the_dictionary_list.keys()
Combinations = list(it.product(*(the_dictionary_list[Name] for Name in AllKeysNames)))
print(f'{Combinations}')
```

Esto imprimirá una `lista` que tiene elementos `360` en total.

Sin embargo, digamos que el orden importa en el caso anterior (es decir, se necesitan permutaciones), este orden sería el siguiente:

```
'Fondo'>'Cuerpo'>'Ojos'>'Color'>'Pinzas'>'Puas'
```

¿Cómo podría hacer un programa que siempre comience con el valor de la llave '**Fondo**', luego agregue el valor de la llave '**Cuerpo**', luego agregue el primer valor de la llave '**Color**'? , luego agrega el primer valor de la llave '**Pinzas**', luego agrega el primer valor de la llave '**Puas**' y así sucesivamente ...?

Al final, la cantidad total de elementos en la nueva lista seguiría siendo `360`, pero esta vez estos elementos se habrían creado siguiendo un orden específico.

Alguna idea?

Comment: Haz `AllKeysNames = ['Fondo', 'Cuerpo'', 'Ojos', 'Color', 'Pinzas', 'Puas']`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ya lo descubrí, gracias a @abulafia, incluso decidí que el usuario sea quien decida cuál será el orden en que se realizarán las permutaciones.

```
# creating an empty list
Keys_input = []
# number of elements
n = len(the_dictionary_list)
i = 0
while True:
    AllKeysNames = the_dictionary_list.keys()
    print('\033[46m'+str(AllKeysNames)+'\033[0m')
    ele = input("\033[0;37;40mTell me which valid key you want me to set now:\033[0m ")
    if ele in the_dictionary_list and ele not in Keys_input:
        Keys_input.append(ele) # adding the element
        i += 1
        print(f'\033[0;37;42mThe array has been updated, its current storage is the following {Keys_input}\033[0m')
        if i == n:
            print("\u001b[45mThe array is now full, let's continue with the next step\033[0m")
            break
    else:
        if ele not in the_dictionary_list:
            print('\u001b[43mPlease, type only valid key names\033[0m')
        if ele in Keys_input:
            print('\u001b[43mStop, that key IS ALREADY SAVED in the array, try with a different valid one\033[0m')
            print(f'\u001b[45mCurrent storage of the array is the following {Keys_input}\033[0m')     
AllKeysNames2 = Keys_input
Combinations = list(it.product(*(the_dictionary_list[Name] for Name in AllKeysNames2)))
print(f'{Combinations}')
```

Comment: Pequeña optimización. No tienes por qué esperar a que `i==n`, puedes parar el bucle cuando `i==n-1` y el que quedaba sin elegir será el último en la ordenación. Puedes ir quitando elementos de `AllKeysNames` a medida que van siendo elegidos.

Comment: Mira, aquí tienes un ejemplo de lo que quiero decir --> https://gist.github.com/abul4fia/da8cf279f39d4d9492869ab83510dd6f Se simplifica bastante el código (no es necesario comprobar si ya estaba elegido, sólo si no está entre las opciones) y al usuario le resultará más fácil ver en cada iteración qué opciones le quedan. Te ahorras también las variables `i` y `n`